# Client side - How do I get the "Location" header of any website?

Tags: javascript

Before you say that this isn't possible, please refer to [here](http://hurl.it). All I need is to stop the redirecting of a automatic redirect url, and get the page that it is trying to redirect to. I prefer the "Position" header, but if there is another way, that would be great.

It doesn't seem like XMLhttpRequest will work, as to send a request, the url has to be on the same domain, which isn't this case. Please help!!!

Comment: There is no `Position` header in HTTP 1.1.

Comment: Also, `XMLHttpRequest` will automatically follow redirects - so I'm not sure what your problem is, exactly.

Comment: @Dai How does that website potentially, "Disable redirects" (and it works, have tested a redirected url)? I would like to figure this out. Also, there IS a position header. I am not sure what exactly to call it, but the site calls it, "response header"

Comment: I think more info is needed. What are you trying to GET? I ask because I  scrape external sites for links and GET the url, prevent redirects and force streams with live video..

Comment: I am trying to GET http://assetgame.roblox.com/asset/?id=1818. There is a redirection link that links to a download url, and http://hurl.it detects it if you set your settings to this: https://gyazo.com/11bd277c94c8c0ad87fc16a6baa64dbc

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like `hurl.it` doesn't use `XMLHttpRequest`, instead they make their own request (server-side) which does let them choose to follow redirections or not (for example, .NET's `HttpWebRequest.AllowAutoRedirect` property).

Whereas in client JavaScript you have to use `XMLHttpRequest` and unfortunately there is no API to disable redirects.

**However** there is a new Web API called [Fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) - supported by Chrome since 42, Edge since release 14, and partial support in Firefox since release 39.

With `Fetch` you *can* choose to not follow redirects, like so:

```
var url = "http://assetgame.roblox.com/asset/?id=1818";
var fetchOptions = {
    redirect: 'manual' // use "manual" to disable the automatic following of redirections
};
var request = new Request( url, fetchOptions );

window
    .fetch( request )
    .then( function( response ) {

        alert( response.headers.get('Location') );

    } );
```

This can be put more succinctly:

```
fetch( "http://assetgame.roblox.com/asset/?id=1818", { redirect: 'manual' } )
    .then( res => alert( res.headers.get('Location') ) );
```

#### UPDATE:

According to the documentation, the `Location` header will not be exposed to clients, unfortunately:

> http://xcatliu.com/fetch/#atomic-http-redirect-handling
>   Throughout the platform, **redirects (a response whose status or internal response's (if any) status is a redirect status) are not exposed to APIs.** Exposing redirects might leak information not otherwise available through a cross-site scripting attack.

So only value added by the `Fetch` API is a more succinct request/response API, and the ability to *detect* redirections and choose to not follow them (unlike `XMLHttpRequest` which will always follow redirections), but you can't get the raw header, unfortunately.

Note that WebSockets do not expose a true TCP socket connection, so you cannot connect to arbitrary network services using WebSockets either.

Comment: It seems that the fetch api is giving me the alert, "Null" when I run this code. I know there is a "location" header, as Hurt.it displays it. Have an idea on how I would use hurl.it's server-side controller to my advantage?

Comment: @Dalrae I looked deeper at the `Fetch` documentation and apparently web-browsers will not display the value of the `Location` header as not to leak information valuable for XSS attacks (apparently). So you can only use the `Fetch` API to determine *if* a redirect happened and to not follow it, but you still won't get the value of the `Location` header using client-script, unfortunately.

Comment: Thank you. I will try to find an API to handle my request.

Comment: Just for completeness: when using `redirect: 'manual'`, Fetch returns an `opaqueredirect` response. An `opaqueredirect` response does not expose any headers at all (neither `Location`). Quote from the docs:


"opaqueredirect: The fetch request was made with redirect: manual. The Response's status is 0, headers are empty, body is null and trailer is empty.". See more information about the different Fetch response types: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/type

Comment: no way to get header response Location?